# what is syntax for round function in vs2015

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to round a calculated value to one decimal place and display it in a textbox.

```
dim rai as decimal
rai = Round(active_insulin,1)
```

Comment: Is this a web site?  Windows forms?  How far did you get?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.Round method.

```
rai= Math.Round(active_insulin,1)
```